# JabRef citation in LibreOffice with institutional author

Tags: latex, libreoffice, bibtex, openoffice-writer

I'm using JabRef as a reference manager and LibreOffice writer as document editor.
I'm using the ooPluging to cite JabRef sources in LibreOffice, but I'm having troubles with sources with institutional authors. For example, the following source

```
@Misc{RevistaSemana2013,
Title                    = {Un buen año para la economía},
HowPublished             = {Online. Available at http://www.foo.bar},
Institution              = {Revista Semana},
Month                    = {Dec},
Year                     = {2013},
Comment                  = {Last visited 21-10-2015},
}
```

will be appear in the references as:
Revista Semana (2013a). Un buen año para la economía. Online. Available at http://www.foo.bar. Last visited 21-10-2015.

But will be cited as (Semana 2013a).
My style file can be found in http://pastebin.com/j5vNgyDR

Thanks,

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: The result should be a citation like (Revista Semana 2013a) since it is an institutional author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like JabRef always splits up the last name, even if it's an institution ([java code](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/jabref/openoffice/OOBibStyle.java#L631)):

```java
AuthorList al = AuthorList.getAuthorList(author);
sb.append(getAuthorLastName(al, 0));
```

However I found a simple workaround.  In the source, use a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) instead of an ordinary space between `Revista` and `Semana`.  Then we get the desired result in LibreOffice:

```
(Revista Semana 2013)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might use an additional curly bracket:

```
{{Revista Semana}}
```

as mentioned in the biblatex manual, section 2.3.3, for corporate authors:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf